# Setting up yii framework environment 2013

Tags: php, yii, netbeans-7, development-environment, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to set up YII framework in netbeans. I have spend the last 2 hours changing and unchanging things and to be honest I am not sure if I have the right setting up for this. I am using netbeans because eclipse is slow and makes my PC slows.

so far I have changes this in the php.ini

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
```

I can't find `xdebug.remote_port` in the file so I included it manually like this

`xdebug.remote_port = 9000`

On this website
[Yii framework netbeans ide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/83/netbeans-ide-and-yii-projects/#hh3)

It says on the **Debugging**

- Install Xdebug (usually already available in your installation):

  - Follow the [official installation instructions](http://xdebug.org/docs/install).
    How do i check if **Xdebug** is already installed? also when I did the download from  *official installation instructions* I got a .dll file and in the video tutorial on youtube *Instalando XAMPP + XDEBUG + NETBEANS 7.3.1(YII PLUGGING) the guy installed a `.nbm` file as the plugging

**Additional info**

I normally config my hosts file to test.local and then just use this for my url and then config the vhost file in xmapp to point to where my project folder is located

I am using netbeans 7.4 and I am trying to know the correct no confusing step on how to set up the correct environment for yii framework.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was download the .nbm file from netbeans plugin list on their website and change the xdebug.

*I asked a some question on yill live chat and I was told I do not need those things for yill to work but its also good practice to set up the framework environment if its the first time using it*